# Pygame for Python3.5 on CentOS 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, installation, centos7

Thanks in advance for the help.

I am trying to install Pygame for Python 3.5.

I have spent many hours doing research and found that it was possible for Windows, yet nothing about CentOS.

**Is it possible to install Pygame for Python 3.5 on CentOS 7?**

**If so, how can i do it?**

I have tried many commands, all of which have not worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: because CentOS is focused more on stability and installing pygame, would lead to you installing certain packages that can become 'unstable'. it's simply not meant for development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile pygame from source code.

1) Get dependances:

```
yum install python3 python3-tools python3-devel SDL SDL-devel portmidi portmidi-devel ffmpeg ffmpeg-devel SDL_image-devel SDL_mixer-devel SDL_ttf-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel  
cd /usr/lib  
ln -s libportmidi.so libporttime.so
```

2) Get pygame source code:

```
svn co svn://seul.org/svn/pygame/trunk pygame
cd pygame
```

3) Then config, compile and install:

```
python3 config.py
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install
```